# Jquery ajax jsonp: Invalid left-hand side assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I've got a room monitor device I'm collecting data from, I can get it work with javascript but not jquery.

With plain javascript, define a function:

```
function myfunction(data){
  console.log(data);
}
```

Then in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://172.16.198.19/getData.jsonp=callback=myfunction"></script>
```

I get an object in console containing all the data. Great!

I now try to get the same result using jQuery's $.ajax but am having problems:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://172.16.198.19/getData.jsonp',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonCallback: 'parseData',
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(){
    console.log("nope");
  }
});
```

This gives me the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Any suggestions on what to try / how to fix are appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: Solved and answered. jQuery formats the query with `_=` in it which the server was rejecting. Working function is thus:

```
  $.ajax('http://172.16.198.19/getData.jsonp', {
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'parseData'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data.sensor[0].tc);
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("nope");
  });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been solved thanks to the very helpful Cork in #jquery on freenode.

The problem was jquery formatting the query with _= in it which the server was rejecting.

The working result is thus:

```
  $.ajax('http://172.16.198.19/getData.jsonp', {
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'parseData'
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }).fail(function() {
    console.log("nope");
  });  
}
```